# context.lookup("datasource") returns org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I am working on project which needs to be deployable on both **weblogic** and **jboss**. I have compiled **wildfly** from sources. Now, I am trying to get datasource using naming. Application is working fine on **JBOSS EAP 6.1**, I am able to get datasource reference as `javax.sql.DataSource` but now in **widlfly**, using following code

```
dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) context.lookup("datasource");
```

it throws exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

if I try using following code,

```
Object obj = context.lookup("datasource");
dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) obj;
```

it doesn't throw the above exception rather on using the datasource, it throws exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource does not implement the requested interface javax.sql.DataSource
```

However, looking at code of class, we can see that it implements the `javax.sql.DataSource`

Can anyone please tell me how can I use the casted `WrapperDataSource` or get datasource returned as `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Server Info:

```
Calling "C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT"

  JAVA: "C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java"

===============================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
16:04:19,731 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
16:04:19,903 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Beta2
16:04:19,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT "WildFly" starting
16:04:21,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:04:21,138 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.1.0.CR7
16:04:21,153 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.1.0.CR7
16:04:21,309 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Beta1
16:04:21,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:04:21,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
16:04:21,372 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.Final
16:04:21,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:04:21,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:04:21,388 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Beta18 starting
16:04:21,403 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Beta18 starting
16:04:21,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
16:04:21,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.0.Final)
16:04:21,450 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:04:21,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:04:21,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:04:21,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
16:04:21,559 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT/welcome-content
16:04:21,700 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
16:04:21,700 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
16:04:21,763 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
16:04:21,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver (version 3.57)
16:04:21,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = DB2Driver
16:04:22,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT\standalone\deployments
16:04:22,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
16:04:22,122 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.1.Final
16:04:22,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:04:22,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/rapiddb]
16:04:22,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:04:22,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:04:22,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.0.0.Beta2-SNAPSHOT "WildFly" started in 2828ms - Started 186 of 223 services (62 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it will have something to do with the way you configure your JDBC driver in the datasource on the server or if you supply another driver in your package that makes a collision with the actual driver you use.

A similar error can be found at https://community.jboss.org/message/250795

If that doesn't work out also post the version of the server in which you encounter the issue.      Just to ensure you are not suffering from fixed data source patches on the server.

Comment: Hi Flip, thanks for the reply, I have **DB2 Driver** configured as static module under **modules** directory. I checked and couldn't find any other copy of **db2jcc.jar** & **db2jcc_license_cu.jar**.

Comment: I have deployed application as EAR and the same application works fine on JBOSS EAP 6.1. Which other driver can have conflict with DB2 Drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the issue on WildFly Forum ([WildFly Thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/233855)) and found that there is another jar containing `javax.sql.DataSource` interface.

I used a utility named jarscan.jar to search the interface in my modules and found that a jar was containing another `javax.sql.DataSource` class. Removing the jar form module resolved the issue.